# How can I accurately measure how many socket connections my server can handle?

Tags: java, server, nio

I have a TCP server, and I'm testing it with a dummy client that consists of a very simple java app that makes a socket connection and sends a byte stream to the server.

I can set the number of connections to use, in a for loop, so if I set it to 100 it'll start 100 threads that connect to the server and dump data.

I'm wondering how I can accurately check how many concurrent connections I have?

For example, if I set the client to make 1,000 connections then I start getting `ConnectException: Connection Refused` after around 600 sockets are connected.

Does that mean it's fair to say the server can handle 500 simultaneous socket connections?
How can I accurately measure this?

If I add a `Thread.sleep()` for 5 nano-seconds between each socket connection then the server doesn't crash at all.

Comment: Leave the sleep in. You're testing the wrong thing. Without the sleep you're testing how fast the server can accept. With the sleep, you're testing how many connections can exist at once. Not the same thing.

Comment: OK, good to know. So with the amount of connections that can exist at once, the sleep needs to be in the client thread after the connection is established. Yes, that makes more sense. Thanks. So I'm on the write track then. Care to write a proper answer?

Answer (score 0):

Use ExecutorService to execute threads instead of thread.start() method.
I hope this will resolve your problem.

Here is a sample code for reference.

```
public class TCPServer{    
  private ExecutorService pool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

  public acceptClients(){
    while(true){
      pool.execute(new ClientListner(serverSocket.accept()));
    }
  }
}

public class ClientListner extends Thread{
  private Socket client;

  public ClientListner(Socket client) {
    this.client = client;
  }

  public void run() {
    //TODO add your code here
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I think you misunderstood my question.  I want to know how to accurately determine how many concurrent connections my server can handle.